# Get key and score of the last inserted item in Redis sorted set

Tags: redis

**Now I made some changes in my solution. What I want to get now is key->score pairs for given range of keys. For example:
set = [1: 3, 2: 5, 7: 8, 10: 1]
for range [2, 8] I want to get: [2: 5, 7: 8]**

How can I get the last inserted (or last 5) items from Redis sorted set. I tried the zrange function, but it takes into account the score when doing the sort. Can I somehow get them sorted by the insertion time? Or,  by the key?

I considered using list, but I need also to access elements by key, and that is why I want to use sorted sets (better access time complexity).

Thanks!

Comment: score you used means something ? maybe you can use timestamp as score?

Comment: yes, the score is important. I edited the question. Now, I would like to get interval based on key range. zrange gives result based on score values.

Comment: Maybe you can add a lua script to do this, once you receive the request, you put data into two zset structure like build a index on 'key', like what we do in RDMS. You will get range by score too ? If not, maybe you can use some algorithm to add keyinfo with score as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your score a composite value : a concatenation of timestamp and the original score.

The first 10 digit are timestamp when the item has been inserted. The x last digit are the score of the item (means you have to add some 0 at the beginning to always have the same number of digit).

Example :  148594228400023

Then, you can get the last 5 inserted items with zrevrangebyscore and retrieve the score of the item.